# C# Indexer on Named Property Wrapper

Tags: c#

I have legacy code that I'm trying to obsolete that I cannot change.  Its a column-based data storage class that can be indexed based on the name of the column. Something like this:

```
StorageClassName scn = new StorageClassName("Property_Name",new double[]{1,2,3});
double[] d = scn["Property_Name"];
```

I'm trying to create some sort of wrapper class that will allow me to implement interfaces/class inheritance.

```
BetterStorageClassName bscn = scn;
double[] d = bscn.PropertyName;
```

What is the best way to accomplish this wrapper class?  It doesn't necessarily need to be implicit.

Edit: I left off the main part of this question.  The answers I got for the first part are good though.  How would I do the conversion the other way?

```
 double[] d = bscn["PropertyName"];
```

I'm assuming this uses reflection in some capacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a class with string indexer and you want to translate that into properties, you could do that using `dynamic`:

```
class StorageClassName : Dictionary<string, double[]>
{}

class DynamicStorageClassName : DynamicObject
{
    private readonly StorageClassName m_storageClassName;

    public DynamicStorageClassName(StorageClassName storageClassName)
    {
        m_storageClassName = storageClassName;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        if (m_storageClassName.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
        {
            result = m_storageClassName[binder.Name];
            return true;
        }

        return base.TryGetMember(binder, out result);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var scn = new StorageClassName { { "PropertyName", new double[] { 1, 2, 3 } } };
dynamic dscn = new DynamicStorageClassName(scn);
Console.WriteLine(dscn.PropertyName[1]);
```

Keep in mind that you pay some performance penalty for using `dynamic` and if the set of properties won't change, you should probably use ordinary properties as others suggested.

If, on the other hand, you had a class with ordinary properties and wanted to translate that to using indexer, you can use reflection:

```
class StaticStorageClassName
{
    public double[] PropertyName { get; set; }

    public StaticStorageClassName()
    {
        PropertyName = new double[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    }
}

class ReverseStorageClassName
{
    private readonly StaticStorageClassName m_staticStorageClassName;

    public ReverseStorageClassName(StaticStorageClassName staticStorageClassName)
    {
        m_staticStorageClassName = staticStorageClassName;
    }

    public double[] this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            var propertyInfo = typeof(StaticStorageClassName).GetProperty(name);
            if (propertyInfo == null)
                throw new ArgumentException();

            return (double[])propertyInfo.GetValue(m_staticStorageClassName, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var sscn = new StaticStorageClassName();
var rscn = new ReverseStorageClassName(sscn);
Console.WriteLine(rscn["PropertyName"][2]);
```

If the various properties have different types, you'd have to make the return type of the indexer either `object` or `dynamic`.

Note that using reflection wouldn't work if `StaticStorageClassName` was implemented using `DynamicObject`.

Answer (score 1):

For the example given, I would imagine it implemented like this:

```
public double[] PropertyName
{
    get { return wrapped["Property_Name"]; }
    set { wrapped["Property_Name"] = value; }
}
```

Are you trying to avoid writing all these wrappers? Or do type conversions?

Answer (score 1):

From your question I guess you want to have full named properties instead of string based keys. In that case you can just provide properties for the access:

```
class BetterStorageClassName : StorageClassName 
{
    public double[] PropertyName
    {
        get { return this["Property_Name"]; }
        set { this["Property_Name"] = value; }
    }
}
```

However that method has several caveats:

- It implies that the properties are fixed and don't really change because otherwise you end up constantly modifying your wrapper.
- The properties can't be dynamically defined at runtime.
- You have to have a wrapper class for each set of properties.